# I want to create a setting screen in a scene using FPSController, but I can not click on the editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Display the UI of the setting screen in the scene using the FPSController, And I want to be able to set up the game (for example, the camera's FOV). 
the mouse cursor is appeared by pushed ESC key.
However, when the FPSController is active, the mouse cursor disappears when clicked and setting can not be made.

I checked the script, FirstPersonController.cs (script for FPSController gameObject), but there was no description about mouse cursor.

The FirstPersonController.cs has not been rewritten. There is a code at the link below.

https://qiita.com/ABCDEEEEEE/items/4f2452a88fb1050684fc

I want to keep the mouse cursor from disappearing even when FPSController is active.

Comment: Did you press the ESC key and the cursor still remained invisible?

Comment: Of course, the mouse cursor is displayed with the ESC key.

Comment: "m_MouseLook.UpdateCursorLock();" ... cursorlock.. some remove the cursor.. Taken from the code you linked..

Comment: I removed m_MouseLook.UpdateCursorLock();.
However, it disappears when I click the screen after displaying the mouse cursor once by pressing the ESC key.How can I prevent it from disappearing by clicking on the screen?